# How to change the window title from a entry box tkinter

Tags: tkinter, python-3.5

What I want to do is make a program that when you press enter in the entry box it changes the window title

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
title = window.title("1")

def name(event):
    title.configure("2")

Name = tkinter.Entry(window)
Name.bind("<Return>", name)
Name.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Any help will be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the window title with Tk.title function.

```
window.title("TITLE")
```

This will change the title.

```
def name(event=None):
    window.title("Hello, %s!"%Name.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
title = window.title("1")

def name(event):
    window.title("2")

Name = tkinter.Entry(window)
Name.bind("<Return>", name)
Name.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: change window.title if you want title same as entry widget value `window.title(Name.get())`